# User control "can't see" NuGet library while Windows Form can

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I want to create an application where by pressing a button, the program dynamically adds tabpages which are made by using a UserControl I made in another project.

Where is the problem?

In the UserControl, I have added a code at clicking a specific button, that -by using a custom library- sends some requests to a server in order to login. That custom library, wants the projects that reference it, have some NuGet packages installed (Microsoft.Net.Http and Microsoft.Bcl.Async).
However, when I click that button, the problem http://prntscr.com/1yjmec appears.
I think that this of course means that it can't see what the NuGet package installed? (I should say here that target .NET Framework is 4.5).

In the meantime, while testing things, I added a mini button for the same job, in the Windows Form Application that was going to use the above UserControl. I did exactly the same process (installed the NuGet packages, referenced the custom library, and wrote the button code), and it worked normally and without errors.

So, is there a specific thing I need to do in order to get it working in a UserControl?

Comment: .Net 4.5 includes those features.  You should remove the NuGet packages.

Comment: When I remove the NuGet packages, I get the same error as above, plus this warning: http://prntscr.com/1yjoya

Comment: Your packages are messed up.  Make sure that all of the projects are referencing .Net 4.5, remove _all_ NuGet packages, and try again.